# Stop iPhone sharing open tabs via bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ipad, bluetooth, data-synchronization, web-browser

If I open a tab on my iPhone using either Safari or Microsoft Edge then if Bluetooth is enabled the same tab opens on my iPad in Edge and an icon like this appears in the dock of the iPad - it's the Edge icon with what looks like a small phone in the top right.

[image: iPad Dock]

Both iPhone (SE 2022) and iPad (Pro, 1st gen) are fully updated on 15.6.1.  They are also linked to the same Apple ID. Microsoft Edge is version 104.0.1293.70 reinstalled from App store today.

Neither Safari or Edge are set to share through *Settings > Profile > iCloud* (so not a duplicate of this question [Stop information syncing between iPad and iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345192/stop-information-syncing-between-ipad-and-iphone)) and neither app has requested bluetooth under *Settings > Privacy > Bluetooth* on either device.

I initially thought it could be Edge syncing via Microsoft account but have reinstalled Edge and not connected an account and it still happens.  New tabs opened on Safari on iPhone are also synced so this is clearly not the case.

- If I disable bluetooth on either device this does not happen.
- If I sign out of my Apple ID on the iPad it also does not happen.

I would like to use Bluetooth and the same Apple ID on both so how do I stop my iPhone syncing open browser tabs in this case? I do not want tabs from my phone appearing on my iPad especially if they are from a different browser.

Comment: It does the same for me, between my 10.14 Mac and my iOS frickin' 12 iPad. It gives me the option of grabbing recent tabs that were open on my Mac.  *I did absolutely nothing to set this up*.  I gather Apple opened up this architecture to 3rd parties.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't iCloud sync, it's Handoff, a part of Continuity.
This allows nearby devices signed into the same Apple ID to share information 'live' between them, so you can start work on one then immediately pick up on another.

See [Apple KB - Use Continuity to connect your Mac, iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, and Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/HT204681)

> Here's how to turn on Handoff:   >
> Mac: choose Apple menu  > System
> Preferences, then click General. Select "Allow Handoff between this
> Mac and your iCloud devices".
>
> iPhone, iPad or iPod touch: go to
> Settings > General > AirPlay & Handoff, then turn on Handoff.

Comment: That was it, disabled now thanks. Incidentally it was opening Edge not Safari as that was my default browser. It seems Handoff opens default browser on iPad irrespective of browser used on iPhone which was confusing.

Comment: Ah, OK. Wasn't aware of that. I don't actually use Handoff here at all.

Comment: Handoff also allows you to share your clipboard across devices.  So you can copy something - like an image - on one device and immediately paste it on another.  That is quite useful to me .